# Spring security go to different application for authentication with request parameter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have one application(Application1) which is SSO enabled and in that URL there is one parameter passed by user which is used along with userid and password for authentication.
For ex: Andrew works in Project department, and there are lot of other departments also. To login into the application he will type URL first as: http://myapp.com/project and then this login page will ask for userid and password. To authenticate Andrew all 3 things are taken into consideration. Userid, password, and department(passed in URL).

Now I am creating another application (Application2) which has spring security. So for authentication purpose I need to go to my Application1 and pass the department from Application2 in the URL. Once the user is authenticated I need to come back in Application2.
I am able to redirect to Application1 from Application2 by using .formLogin().loginPage() but have no clue in passing the department to URL runtime and come back to Application2 after authentication.

Please help me here.

Comment: The department would be entered by the user in Application2? Or would it be extracted from the url used to log in to application 2?

Comment: Extracted from URL

Comment: @NatFar - The other application which is already developed Applciation1 it extracts the department from URL and authenticate the user. I have no clue in coming back to Application2 after authentication. Please help me here.

Comment: So you need to find a way to 1) Use the url in application 2 to dynamically redirect to the corresponding login page in application 1 and 2) after authenticating in application 1, redirecting to the corresponding url in application 2. Is this correct?

Comment: @NatFar - Yes thats correct. If it can be done via spring security that would be great. So in Application2 I can have my login form of Application1 and then come back to Application2 mentioning that user is authenticated or not.

Comment: So your application 1 is like the SSO authorization server? Are you implementing your own SSO technology? Because application 1 would have to communicate to application 2 whether authentication has been successful. I don't know how your application1 handles that...

Comment: To start, if you want to redirect to the loginpage (and for it to be chosen dynamically based on the url), I would recommend creating your own filter and bypassing the formLogin()